# malloc non-deterministic behaviour

Tags: c, malloc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{      
  int *arr = (int*)malloc(10);
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<100;i++)
  {
    arr[i]=i;
    printf("%d", arr[i]); 
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I am running above program and a call to malloc will allocate 10 bytes of memory and since each int variable takes up 2 bytes so in a way I can store 5 int variables of 2 bytes each thus making up my total 10 bytes which I dynamically allocated.

But on making a call to for-loop it is allowing me to enter values even till 99th index and storing all these values as well. So in a way if I am storing 100 int values it means 200 bytes of memory whereas I allocated only 10 bytes.

So where is the flaw with this code or how does malloc behave? If the behaviour of malloc is non-deterministic in such a manner then how do we achieve proper dynamic memory handling?

Comment: But malloc(10) is not dynamic. Malloc(N*sizeof(int))  is dynamic. You could use int arr[10] if 10 is always 10.

Comment: ... and avoid the (admittedly near-meaningless) memory leak.

Comment: Nobody ever told you not to cast the malloc return value?

Comment: This isn't just "non-deterministic", it's "undefined".

Answer (score 2):

The flaw is in your expectations. You lied to the compiler: *"I only need 10 bytes"* when you actually wrote 100*sizeof(int) bytes. Writing beyond an allocated area is **undefined behavior** and anything may happen, ranging from nothing to what you expect to crashes.

Answer (score 1):

If you do silly things expect silly behaviour.

That said `malloc` is usually implemented to ask the OS for chunks of memory that the OS prefers (like a page) and then manages that memory. This speeds up future mallocs especially if you are using lots of mallocs with small sizes. It reduces the number of context switches that are quite expensive.

Comment: Is using a big array/allocation to do in-place calculations better than having many small allocations? Can `malloc` guarantee that a single 1GB alocation will be completely contiguous address space?

Comment: Each malloc returns a continuous memory of the specified size (or NULL).

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik Per C9899 7.22.3.4, `malloc()` *"The malloc function allocates space for an object whose size is specified by size and whose value is indeterminate."* Contiguous is in the eye of the beholder, but as far as you are concerned, yes, it is contiguous if it is from a **single** call to `malloc()`.

Answer (score 0):

`malloc` behaves exactly as it states, allocates n number bytes of memory, nothing more. Your code might run on your PC, but operating on non-allocated memory is undefined behavior.

A small note...

Int might not be 2 bytes, it varies on different architectures/SDKs. When you want to allocate memory for n integer elements, you should use `malloc( n * sizeof( int ) )`.

All in short, **you** manage dynamic memory with other tools that the language provides ( `sizeof`, `realloc`, `free`, etc. ).

Comment: "you must do `arr[i*sizeof( int )] = i`, not `arr[i]` = i"; this is exactly wrong.  The subscript `i` will access the `i`'th *element* of the array, not the `i`'th *byte*, regardless of type.

Comment: Yep, arr is int* type, so 'i' will be just enough. Thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in the most Operating Systems the size of int is 4 bytes. You can check that with:
`printf("the size of int is %d\n", sizeof(int));`
When you call the malloc function you allocate size at heap memory. The heap is a set aside for dynamic allocation. There's no enforced pattern to the allocation and deallocation of blocks from the heap; you can allocate a block at any time and free it at any time. This makes it much more complex to keep track of which parts of the heap are allocated or free at any given time. Because your program is small and you have no collision in the heap you can run this for with more values that 100 and it runs too. 
When you know what are you doing with malloc then you build programs with proper dynamic memory handling. When your code has improper malloc allocation then the behaviour of the program is "unknown". But you can use gdb debugger to find where the segmentation will be revealed and how the things are in heap.

Comment: The printf has undefined behavior since the format specifier does not match the actual argument. Signed and unsigned types are **not** interchangeable. C99 even has introduced a format specifier for size_t. You look it up :-)

Comment: We can use `%zu` as size_t is unsigned int

Comment: Almost. `%zu` is correct, but size_t can be *any* unsigned type.

Answer (score 0):

C doesn't do any bounds-checking on array accesses; if you define an array of 10 elements, and attempt to write to `a[99]`, the compiler won't do anything to stop you.  The behavior is *undefined*, meaning the compiler isn't required to do anything in particular about that situation.  It may "work" in the sense that it won't crash, but you've just clobbered *something* that may cause problems later on.

When doing a `malloc`, don't think in terms of *bytes*, think in terms of *elements*.  If you want to allocate space for N integers, write

```
int *arr = malloc( N * sizeof *arr );
```

and let the compiler figure out the number of bytes.